# MySQL Query On The Same Table Different Columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables: Project and ProjectFieldValue

I am needing to return results from the ProjectFieldValue based on multiple different key/value options in the table. I can get it to work with one key/value pair, but once I add another AND statement to the query it returns nothing.

Here is a sample of my tables followed by my query...

**Project Table**

```
 ----------------------
 id | name
 ----------------------
 1  | Project #1
```

**ProjectFieldValue Table**

I have millions of records like this and they are all stored in this table and associated to a specific Project.

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 id | project_id     | text_value      | date_value           | field_key
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | 1              | Active          | NULL                 | contract_status
 2  | 1              | NULL            | 2020-06-02 00:01:58  | listing_date
 3  | 1              | Seller          | NULL                 | contract_client_type
 4  | 1              | Active          | NULL                 | contract_option
```

**Here are my queries broken down by what works and doesn't work:**

This does work, but, it is searching on 1 key/value pair...

```
SELECT      p.name, p.id
FROM        ProjectFieldValue pfv
LEFT JOIN   Project p
 ON         pfv.project_id = p.id
WHERE       (pfv.text_value IN ( SELECT text_value FROM ProjectFieldValue WHERE text_value IN     ('Active')) AND field_key = 'contract_status')
GROUP BY    p.id
```

This doesn't work because it is searching on 3 key/value pairs...

```
SELECT      p.name, p.id
FROM        ProjectFieldValue pfv
LEFT JOIN   Project p
 ON         pfv.project_id = p.id
WHERE       (pfv.text_value IN ( SELECT text_value FROM ProjectFieldValue WHERE text_value IN ('Active')) AND field_key = 'contract_status')
AND         (pfv.text_value IN ( SELECT text_value FROM ProjectFieldValue WHERE text_value IN ('Seller')) AND field_key = 'contract_client_type')
AND         (pfv.date_value between '2020-07-08 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-11 23:59:59' AND pfv.field_key = 'listing_date')
GROUP BY    p.id
```

**Goal**

Ultimately, what I would need to be able to do is search on unlimited key/value pairs in this table and return all results grouped by the p.id

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the thing.

```
SELECT      p.name, p.id
FROM        ProjectFieldValue pfv
LEFT JOIN   Project p
    ON      pfv.project_id = p.id
WHERE       (field_key = 'contract_status' AND pfv.text_value = 'Active')
    OR      (field_key = 'contract_client_type' AND pfv.text_value = 'Seller')
    OR      (pfv.field_key = 'listing_date' AND pfv.date_value between '2020-07-08 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-11 23:59:59')
GROUP BY    p.id;
```

But I have doubt why you are Left joining Project and ProjectFieldValue. A simple Inner Join should solve your purpose. As you are grouping by on p.id. You may encourage a lot of NULLed columns. So I would suggest below.

```
SELECT      p.name, p.id
FROM        Project p
JOIN        ProjectFieldValue pfv
    ON      p.id = pfv.project_id
WHERE       (field_key = 'contract_status' AND pfv.text_value = 'Active')
    OR      (field_key = 'contract_client_type' AND pfv.text_value = 'Seller')
    OR      (pfv.field_key = 'listing_date' AND pfv.date_value between '2020-07-08 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-11 23:59:59')
GROUP BY    p.id;
```

Comment: In the case I presented, I need results where all conditions are true (match): contract_status == Active, contract_client_type == Seller, & listing_date needs to be between '2020-07-08 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-11 23:59:59' ... The problem I see is that the SQL above is using "OR" and not "AND" which means that this will return results that may match one conditional but not the other conditionals and the table results will be incorrect.

Comment: @LargeTune how contact status can be Active as well as Seller for a single row?